# expand extremities of R matrix with zeroes

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix pulled from other data that is a fixed dimension and would like to add columns and rows of zeroes at the extremities of this matrix efficiently as I repeat the process 1000+ times, right now I have I use a loop and cbind and rbind. Is there an easier way of doing this?

```
##my actual matrix is real data of fixed dimension.. so i can't simply 
##initialize a larger matrix like I could in this example..

my_matrix <- matrix(1,ncol=10,nrow=10)
for(i in 1:10){
   my_matrix <- cbind(my_matrix,0)
   my_matrix <- rbind(my_matrix,0)
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additive `cbind` and `rbind` in a for loop is really slow. Do it like this instead:

```
new_mat <- matrix(0, ncol=20,nrow=20)
new_mat[1:nrow(my_matrix), 1:ncol(my_matrix)] <- my_matrix
```

Explanation: Create a matrix of zeroes of the desired dimensions, then replace the relevant subset area with your data